# Access Form Image Frame Not Clearing When Switching Tabs

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a form that has three image frames that update based off a three file paths that are stored in the source and on the form itself. I put in the below code to try to get the pictures to clear if the specific tab's file paths were to be null. Now no picture will show up even if there is a file path.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

On Error Resume Next
If IsNull([Me!PicPath1]) Then Me!PIC1.Picture isblank Else Me![PIC1].Picture = Me![PicPath1]
If IsNull([Me!PicPath2]) Then Me!PIC2.Picture isblank Else Me![PIC2].Picture = Me![PicPath2]
If IsNull([Me!PicPath3]) Then Me!PIC3.Picture isblank Else Me![PIC3].Picture = Me![PicPath3]

'This was the first set up code I used to make sure the paths worked.
'Me![PIC1].Picture = Me![PicPath1]
'Me![PIC2].Picture = Me![PicPath2]
'Me![PIC3].Picture = Me![PicPath3]

End Sub
```

Comment: You start with `On Error Resume Next` and follow that up with clearly invalid code (what's `Me!PIC1.Picture isblank` even supposed to mean? Is isblank some constant and do you mean to do `Me!PIC1.Picture = isblank`?), then wonder why you don't get the desired result. Never do `On Error Resume Next`, especially if code isn't working as intended.

Comment: That pretty much fixed my problem. Had a run time error but fixed it by removing the [] from around `Me!PicPath`